# IBM Cloud: How to add Tekton Catalog to Continuous Delivery toolchain configuration?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, continuous-delivery, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am using the [Continuous Delivery service in IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/ContinuousDelivery?topic=ContinuousDelivery-getting-started). My toolchain is defined using a YAML file and stored in the [**.bluemix** directory](https://github.com/open-toolchain/sdk/wiki/Creating-Custom-Toolchain-Templates) in my GitHubcode repository. I am using Tekton for the pipeline. How can I add the [Tekton Catalog](https://github.com/open-toolchain/tekton-catalog) to the toolchain? It should be an existing repo and not to be cloned or forked.

Specifying **existing** instead of **clone** as type did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Wiki in the open-toolchain/sdk repo](https://github.com/open-toolchain/sdk/wiki) has only basic information about how to specify GitHub integration. After looking through many [code samples](https://github.com/open-toolchain/secure-kube-toolchain/blob/master/.bluemix/toolchain.yml#L61) and related testing I found that the following [service specification in the toolchain.yml](https://github.com/open-toolchain/sdk/wiki/Template-File-Format#services-section) works:

```
services:
  tekton-catalog:
    service_id: githubpublic
    parameters:
      repo_url: "https://github.com/open-toolchain/tekton-catalog"
      source_repo_url: "https://github.com/open-toolchain/tekton-catalog"
      type: "link"
      has_issues: false
      enable_traceability: false
      kind: ['pipeline']
```

The `type: "link"` refers to an existing repository. The repo URLs refer to the mentioned [tekton-catalog](https://github.com/open-toolchain/tekton-catalog). What is interesting is that by specifying `kind: ['pipeline']` the repo configuration is not specified in the configuration dialog, but integrated as specified.

In your **tekton.yml** add a reference to the configured catalog in the input section and referencing an environment variable that you declared for the pipeline in the **toolchain.yml**. Something like

```
inputs:
- type: git
  branch: master
  service: ${TEKTON_CATALOG_REPO}
  path: container-registry
```

with TEKTON_CATALOG_REPO based on

```
 TEKTON_CATALOG_REPO: tekton-catalog
```

set as environment variable for the specific toolchain part.